# Quicktime plugin

Tags: html, video, quicktime

I have used the following code to use a webpage player to play .mov videos. But every time i run the page it says, to download quicktime plugin. I have installed latest quicktime plugin. But it dont play the video.

```
 <embed src=
   "http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ibmlinux.mov"
  Pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" width="320"
  height="250" CONTROLLER="true" LOOP="false" AUTOPLAY="true" name="IBM Video">
  </embed>
```

Comment: Question for http://superuser.com